# AppendChild не присваивает класс div-ам

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер. Такой вопрос

Разметка:

```
<body>
    <input id="newcarousel" type="button" value="Добавить карусель"></input>
</body>
```

При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает JS:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div);
document.querySelector("body div:last-child").classList.add("carousel");
```

после трёх нажатий кнопки результат такой:

```
<div class="carousel"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Почему?

код на jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQU86/

Comment: Не по теме: а зачем ставить закрывающий тег input? Лишние трафик только.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/E8tMp/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <input id="newcarousel" type="button" value="Добавить карусель">
    </input>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", Init, false);
function Init()
{       
        alert("!!");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.classList.add("carousel");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, объясните что я сделал не так?